# Interrail discount and birthday

Tags: trains, interrail

I plan to buy an interrail ticket for March, but during the month I will turn 28. The discount for the Interrail ticket is until you turn 28 years.

Hence, when I start my trip, I'll be 27, and when I finish it, 28. Should I buy the Youth ticket or the Adult ticket?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the following source: [Interrail.eu](https://www.interrail.eu/de/sonderangebote/ermaessigungen-fuer-jugendliche-bei-interrail?) the age at the first day of your travel is important.

> The reduced prices can be found in the price lists of the Interrail Pass under the "Youth" tab. If you are at least 28 years old on the first day of your Interrail trip, you will need an Adult Pass.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Ingo. I added a bit to your answer, as links can break, and it's helpful to include the reference.

Comment: But it doesn't explicitly say what happens in my case, right?

Comment: @PedroA.Castillejo according to your question, you will be 27 on the first day of your trip via the trains; that's when your Pass would be validated for use. Once that happens, you can continue to use it for the time period allowed on the Pass you buy (such as 5 days or 30 days).

Comment: Pedro, if the issuing website (which you should have consulted first) is not enough of a reference for you, why take the word of a stranger on the net?  Do as you were going to anyway

Comment: @Giorgio I think the point he's making is that the website doesn't explicitly say that you don't need an Adult Pass if you turn 28 during the ticket validity (which it doesn't!) - but I think the intent of the statement is fairly clear as you're saying.